# What is "augmented algebra"?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, definitions, soft-question

Really sorry for this question, but googling for some time did not help me. I was trying to understand the meaning of the following phrase:

*Let B be an augmented algebra over a semi-simple algebra T.*

But I am stuck already with "augmented algebra"... -- can not find a definition on the web.

Comment: The notion of an augmented algebra is defined, for example, in Mac Lane's book Homology. There an augmented algebra $A$ over a field $k$ is a $k$-algebra that is also equipped with an algebra homomorphism $A \rightarrow k$ (the augmentation map). So in your context, I would assume that $B$ is a $T$-algebra that is also equipped with an algebra homomorphism $B \rightarrow T$.

Comment: It probably means that there is a map $\iota : T \to B$ of rings ($B$ is a $T$-algebra) which admits a splitting $\epsilon : B \to T$ (i.e. $\epsilon \circ \iota = 1_T$)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An *augmented ring* is simply a triple $(A,M,\epsilon)$ with $A$ ring, $M$ a left $A$-module and $\epsilon:A\to M$ a surjection of $A$ modules. One says then that $A$ is augmented over $M$. You can find this defined in Cartan-Eilenberg, for example.

Often, $M$ is itself a ring and the map $\epsilon$ is also a ring morphism. This is probably the situation you have.

Comment: C-E also define *supplemented algebras*: a supplemented $k$-algebra is a $k$-algebra augmented over $k$ with $k$-linear augmentation. This is the concept that appears in the comments above. The name comes from the fact that in a supplemented algebra $A$ the base ring $k$ is a summand with a supplement, namely the kernel of the augmentation.

Comment: Mariano, thanks a lot for a super quick answer! Just one more question. Why one would introduce the special name for such type of triples. Do they often pop up?


Comment: I don't know who introduced the concept, but they surely come up often enough. In the context of Cartan-Eilenberg (it may well be they who came up with the notion) it serves as a unifying concept used to set up several different cohomology theories. (The *supplemented algebra* term is mostly unused nowadays, I'd say, but supplemented algebras are of course also all over the place)

Comment: It appears they were indeed the inventors, at least according to Mac Lane classic review of the book (see http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.bams/1183521097&page=record) «Another danger of shiny new notions is that sometimes the shine proves illusory. For example, the authors define an augmented ring [...] Hence "augmented ring" is a new name for "left ideal in a ring."» The review is a must read.

